# I can't get infowindows to display in the public version of my Carto map

Tags: carto

I've got a fairly basic map with 3 layers: https://open-data-charter.carto.com/viz/844cc5da-34a9-11e6-810e-0e3ff518bd15/public_map.

For countries and cities I have selected infowindows to come up when you hover over either the countries or cities. In the Carto editor the infowindows appears for both cities and countries, however, in the public version of the map it only works for countries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the vizjson is not showing any field on the `tooltip` array. There is a workaround that will fix this issue: exporting the map as a carto file and importing it again into your account.